# Is it possible to send @Fields with multipart in retrofit2?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm using retrofit2, i was sending data through it using @FormUrlEncoded because everything was as a string even images but i faced some errors when i send collection of images as strings, so i changes to multipart.

Now i'm facing problem that i can't send @Field of string with multipart.

So, how i can solve this problem without using RequestBody for every string?

here's my code

```
@Multipart
@POST("/androidfiles/insertNews.php")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part file, @Part("name") RequestBody name,
                               @Field("tArabic") String arabicTitle,
                               @Field("tEnglish") String englishTitle,
                               @Field("tRussian") String russianTitle,
                               @Field("tItalian") String italianTitle,
                               @Field("dArabic") String arabicDescription,
                               @Field("dEnglish") String englishDescription,
                               @Field("dRussian") String russianDescription,
                               @Field("dItalian") String italianDescription);
```

and here.

```
private void insertNews(Uri uri){

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ServiceConstants.URL)
            .build();


    File file = FileUtil.getFile(this, uri);

    RequestBody mFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
    MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), mFile);
    RequestBody filename = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), file.getName());

    ApiConfig apiConfig = retrofit.create(ApiConfig.class);

    Call<ResponseBody> addNews = apiConfig.uploadImage(fileToUpload,
            filename,
            etArabicTitle.getText().toString(),
            etEnglishTitle.getText().toString(),
            etRussianTitle.getText().toString(),
            etItalianTitle.getText().toString(),
            etArabicDescription.getText().toString(),
            etEnglishDescription.getText().toString(),
            etRussianDescription.getText().toString(),
            etItalianDescription.getText().toString());

    addNews.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            Toast.makeText(News.this, "success" + "\n" + response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(News.this,Menu.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(News.this, "fail" + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using **multipart requests** using Retrofit, you can pass extra parameters using `@Part` annotation having `RequestBody` fields for additional parameters.

So, You can pass it as `RequestBody` type for all parameters except multipart body like below :

```
@Multipart
@POST("/androidfiles/insertNews.php")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part file,
                               @Part("name") RequestBody name,
                               @Part("tArabic") RequestBody arabicTitle,
                               @Part("tEnglish") RequestBody englishTitle,
                               @Part("tRussian") RequestBody russianTitle,
                               @Part("tItalian") RequestBody italianTitle,
                               @Part("dArabic") RequestBody arabicDescription,
                               @Part("dEnglish") RequestBody englishDescription,
                               @Part("dRussian") RequestBody russianDescription,
                               @Part("dItalian") RequestBody italianDescription);
```

Now, for calling such **API**; you'll need to pass it by creating `RequestBody` for additional parameters as **MIME Type** `text/plain` using syntax `(i.e. RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), your variable goes here))`

During API build up, you can pass call it as:

```
Call<ResponseBody> addNews = apiConfig.uploadImage(fileToUpload,
            filename,
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), etArabicTitle.getText().toString()), //This will make it as RequestBody to pass it along image/files.
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), etEnglishTitle.getText().toString()),
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), etRussianTitle.getText().toString()),
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), etItalianTitle.getText().toString()),
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), etArabicDescription.getText().toString()),
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), etEnglishDescription.getText().toString()),
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), etRussianDescription.getText().toString()),
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), etItalianDescription.getText().toString()));
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

try changing `@Field` to `@Part` . like this :

```
    @Multipart
@POST("/androidfiles/insertNews.php")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part file, @Part("name") RequestBody name,
                               @Part("tArabic") String arabicTitle,
                               @Part("tEnglish") String englishTitle,
                               @Part("tRussian") String russianTitle,
                               @Part("tItalian") String italianTitle,
                               @Part("dArabic") String arabicDescription,
                               @Part("dEnglish") String englishDescription,
                               @Part("dRussian") String russianDescription,
                               @Part("dItalian") String italianDescription);
```